# Find a match from a list of regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of regular expressions in the form of [a-z]* (for example your*). I need to find the possible matches for words read from a regular text file from the list of regular expressions. I can use the Pattern class for each of the list items and then use matcher to match the word with each member of the list, but this process seems time consuming. The regex list is big (around 2500 expressions) and the number of words I need to match is also large (in millions) so I need something fast- and it should be in Java. Is there a better way to search for a regex match for a word from a list of regexes?

Comment: I would suggest to avoid regexps usage for large texts processing, unless that is the requirement - they are not fast enough. There may be much better solution depending on your pattern - e.g. [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)

Comment: Don't think you're approaching your problem well...but, one way to optimize would be sorting your list of regex: expressions with a *high likelihood of a match* and/or *small number of steps to process* should go first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved the problem using a Trie tree.

Answer (score 0):

If all your expressions are all in the form `foo*` then could you not just replace all the pattern match attempts to calls to `word.startsWith(pattern)`?  (Having first trimmed the '*' from the pattern, if is is actually included in the pattern list.)  Or - if the '*' is optional - with either that for `word.equals(pattern)` depending on the pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using a Trie tree. – Farig Sadeque